# else statement not adding content into textarea

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a function below where the if statement works when it comes to adding content into a single textarea when clicking the "Add" button:

```
function addwindow(questionText) { 

    if(window.console) console.log();

    if($(plusbutton_clicked).attr('id')=='mainPlusbutton') { 
        $('#mainTextarea').val(questionText); 
        } else { 
            $(plusbutton_clicked).parent('td').next('td.question').find('textarea.textAreaQuestion').val(questionText);
            }

    $.modal.close(); 
    return false;
}
```

The problem is the else statement is not working when it comes to adding content within one of the appended textareas. What I want is that if a user clicks on a Plus button and adds a content by clicking on the "Add" button, the textarea which belongs in the same row as the plus button which was clicked on will add the content. What do I need to change in order to do this?

Below is the code whch shows the textareas and plus buttons which are appended:

```
    var plusbutton_clicked;

 function insertQuestion(form) {


var $tbody = $('#qandatbl > tbody'); 
var $tr = $("<tr class='optionAndAnswer' align='center'></tr>");
var $plusrow = $("<td class='plusrow'></td>");
var $question = $("<td class='question'></td>");


 $('.questionTextArea').each( function() {

 var $this = $(this);
var $questionText = $("<textarea class='textAreaQuestion'></textarea>").attr('name',$this.attr('name')+"[]")
.attr('value',$this.val());

 $question.append($questionText);

});

 $('.plusimage').each( function() {

var $this = $(this);
var $plusimagerow = $("<a onclick='return plusbutton();'><img src='Images/plussign.jpg' width='30' height='30' alt='Look Up Previous Question' class='imageplus'/></a>").attr('name',$this.attr('name')+"[]")
.attr('value',$this.val());

$plusrow.append($plusimagerow);

 });

$tr.append($plusrow);
$tr.append($question);
$tbody.append($tr);                     

}
```

Below is the php code where it displays the "QuestionContent" and "Add" button for each row. When user clicks on the "Add" button it adds the "QuestionContent" into the single textarea on top but not in the multiple textareas which are appended.

```
  <?php

    $output = "";

            while ($questionrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($questionresult)) {
    $output .= "
    <table>
          <tr>
          <td class='addtd'><button type='button' class='add' onclick='parent.addwindow();'>Add</button></td>
          </tr>";
            }
            $output .= "        </table>";

            echo $output;

            ?>
```

You can view application [here](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/QandATable2.php). Please follow the steps to use the application:

1. Click on "Add Question" button, then will add a textarea within a new row.
2. Click on the "Green Plus" button within the table row you just added, a modal window will appear.
3. In modal window it displays a search bar, in search bar type in "AAA" and click on "Search" button
4. Results will appear of your search, click on "Add" button to add a row. You will find out modal window is closed but the content from the "Question" field is not added in the textarea within the row you clicked on the green plus button

If you did the steps in the top textarea (the one above the horizontal line), then it does work, it just doesn't work for textarea which you have just added

Comment: why do you use `$(this).val()` and `$(this).attr('value', /* somethig */)` instead of `this.value` ?

Comment: What the 'value' does is that if the user enters in text in the single textarea and then click on "Add Question" button, it will add that text in the next textarea added. This is completly different from what I am doing here and I did not include code to show this above. Without the 'value' then it will always display blank textarea when user clicks on "Add Question", even if there was text entered within the textarea

Comment: I included URL of application so you can see for yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your errors:

```
$('.plusimage').live('click', function() {
    plusbutton($(this));
});
```

You're using jQuery 1.7 in your page, the `.live` method has been deprecated since jQuery `1.7`. You should use `.on` instead.

You're also triggering your `plusbutton` function in your generated links:

```
<a value="" name="plusbuttonrow[]" onclick="return plusbutton();">
```

Which isn't passing any element as parameter to your `plusbutton` function be stored in your global var `plusbutton_clicked` which you are expecting. There's no reference to the clicked element then, therefore it doesn't find any element when you use the `plusbutton_clicked` var in the `addwindow` function.

Either keep the `.on` method or the `onclick` calls above to prevent the function from being fired twice.

There might be other errors as well (e.g. You're checking for id attributes which do not exist for the dynamically generated elements), but this is the main one. Also, I wonder if you don't have any deadline to finish this, it's the 10th time I see this question in the previous 3 weeks.. At least you made some progress, congratz.

Comment: I have found out that if I change the .live function to .on, then it doesn't add any content into the single textarea at all while before it did so I need the .live() function. I also tried adding same function as above but changed it to .imageplus to see if it works for dynamic textareas but still no luck

Comment: Changing the `$('.plusimage').live('click'` by `$('.plusimage').on('click'` won't open the modal? Doesn't make much sense but anyway, your `plusbutton()` is being called twice, while the call in the `<a>`s don't pass any parameter. Try removing the links' `onclick` and add `href='#'` to them: `var $plusimagerow = $("<a href='#'>`, if your `.live` is working, it'll trigger when you click the image and open the modal. Check if it makes any difference.

Comment: If I do what you stated, then when I click on the image button with in one of the rows, it does not open up a modal window. It only opens up for the Image button which belongs to the textarea on the top